# Get directory path from full filepath

Tags: objective-c, path, nsstring

New to objective-c. How do I get the directory from a full file path?

so if I have

```
/User/Test/Desktop/test.txt
```

I want

```
/User/Test
```

Also is there an equivalent to Path.Combine from .NET in Objective-C?

Comment: So you always want the grand parent directory of the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-[NSString pathComponents]` returns an `NSArray` of path components.

For instance

```
NSString *path = @"/User/Test/Desktop/test.txt";
NSArray *components = [path pathComponents];
NSLog(@"%@", components); //=> ( /, User, Test, Desktop, test.txt )
```

Then you can take only the components you need and build a new path with them, for instance

```
NSString *newPath =
    [NSString pathWithComponents:
        [components subarrayWithRange:(NSRange){ 0, components.count - 2}]];
NSLog(@"%@", newPath); // => /User/Test/
```

Answer (score 4):

Read the *Working with Paths* section of Apple's [`NSString` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW38), you will find methods that answer your questions. For example, `stringByDeletingLastPathComponent` removes the last component of a path leaving the containing directory.